# office web apps integration

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, sharepoint-api

We would like to allow users of our site display office documents in Office WebApps. Since the Office WebApps are allowed only for skydrive or sharepoint and we have lot of documents for lots of tenants we have chosen to use sharepoint online.
The idea is to upload documents to sharepoint and get public shared access link so we can redirect  browser there and run office web app.

Is there an API that will allow us to upload document to sharepoint online and get public shared access link?

Any other approaches to integrate Office WebApps without installing WebApps server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default link to the item (retrieving this will be different depending on how you are uploading the documents) and then [configure SharePoint to open the documents by default using the Office WebApps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx).

Comment: And the default link will be accessible by anonymous users? Because I need a shared access link. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can set up the document library to allow anonymous users access or an individual item